# How to open terminal and run a command to it in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to open a terminal and run a command using python . I want to run `rsync` command and see live progress of that command on terminal . I can use subprocess and grab the output of `rsync` but i can get output only after finish of subprocess . I want live progress of the `rsync` command on terminal.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess

command = subprocess.Popen(["rsync -apvr source destination --progress"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = command.communicate()
```

can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you do **not** need `shell=True`. Use this instead:

```
subprocess.Popen(["rsync", "-apvr", "source", "destination", "--progress"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Or, if you don't want to manually split the command line:

```
import shlex

subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("rsync -apvr source destination --progress"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Second: `communicate` waits the end of the process. If you want to actually mix the output of the subprocess with the current process you can simply avoid specifying `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, or maybe you could specify `stdout=sys.stdout` if you want to be explicit:

```
import sys

subprocess.Popen(["rsync", "-apvr", "source", "destination", "--progress"], stdout=sys.stdout)
```

this will print the output of `rsync` in the stdout of your process.

If you instead want to parse the output "in real time" you'll have to use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and read from `Popen.stdout` manually:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["rsync", "-apvr", "source", "destination", "--progress"], stdout=sys.stdout)

for line in proc.stdout:
    do_something(line)
```

Depending on exactly what you want to do you may want to use the `select` module to get "non blocking reads" etc.